# redux : Select/get nested State by dynamic keys

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

Here my redux state  , the state has dynamic nested object name

```
    const search = {
     client :
    { result: [],
      selected: null,
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: false,},
 [dynamicKey] :
    { result: [],
      selected: null,
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: false,},
 [dynamicKey2] :
    { result: [],
      selected: null,
      isLoading: false,
      isSuccess: false,}

    };
```

I'm trying to get nested object by dynamic key , here is my selector code :

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";

export const searchState = (state) => state.search;

export const selectSearch = (keyRef) =>
  createSelector([searchState], (search) => search[keyRef]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to ask the question but your code looks fine as it is. In the component you can use useMemo to not needlessly create the selector:

```
//renamed the selector to create...
export const createSelectSearch = (keyRef) =>
  createSelector([searchState], (search) => search[keyRef]);

//compnent example
const MyComponent = ({keyRef}) => {
  const selectSearch = React.useMemo(
    ()=>createSelector(keyRef),//create the selector when keyRef changes
    [keyRef]
  );
  const result = useSelector(selectSearch)
  return <jsx />
}
```

Some more information about this pattern can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors)